# Getting NPM error: "Resolving deps of app\app.ts failed."

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular

I'm trying to install and utilize [this brunch.io skeleton](https://github.com/colinbate/ng2-brunch). I keep running into this error:

```
20 Apr 19:40:21 - info: application started on http://localhost:3333/
20 Apr 19:40:24 - info: compiling
20 Apr 19:40:28 - error: Resolving deps of app\app.ts failed. Could not load module 'app\home' from 'C:\Users\tyler.WORKGROUP\Documents\GitHub\zenith-folio\app'. Possible solution: add 'app' to package.json and `npm install`.
20 Apr 19:40:28 - error: Resolving deps of app\about\index.ts failed. Could not load module 'app\about\about.tpl' from 'C:\Users\tyler.WORKGROUP\Documents\GitHub\zenith-folio\app\about'. Possible solution: add 'app' to package.json and `npm install`.
20 Apr 19:40:28 - info: compiling.
20 Apr 19:40:29 - info: compiled 477 files into 2 files, copied index.html in 8.4 sec
```

I'm trying my best to understand what's going on here, but I'm not sure. I can see that I need to add "app" to package.json, but I don't know how or which "app" it's specifying. Is it talking about:

- the folder called "app"
- a file called app.ts

Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post some code? On how are trying to import those modules and your tsconfig file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message is pretty clear: `Could not load module 'app\home'`, it means that you have unresolved import in `app.ts` which possibly looks like `import ... from 'app\home';`

Comment: So does that mean whatever's in app.ts is causing the error? Looking at it, it looks like it's referencing the `app\home` locations just fine.

Comment: maybe `app/home`? you should have existing `app/home.ts`

Comment: No such file exists inside the home folder - just an `index.html`. This could be the root of the issue. I'll have to contact the developer, then! Thanks.